# MySQL Full text Search one is to many

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, full-text-search, fulltext-index

**Problem:** I need to do a full text search on a field that has multiple rows (one to many).

**I have these schema:**

*Company* (15 MILLION+++)

-id

-companyname

*Category*

-companyid

-categoryname (W/ FULLTEXT INDEX)

**Sample Data:**

*Company*

id | companyname

1  | CompanyA

*Category*

companyid | categoryname

1         | banking
1         | finance

**Goal:**
I need to get all companies that offers "banking finance" but by using IN BOOLEAN MODE and EXACT MATCH.

The query below will not have a result since "banking" and "finance" are on separate rows:

```
SELECT c.companyname FROM Company c
INNER JOIN Categoy cat ON c.id = cat.companyid
WHERE MATCH (categoryname) AGAINST ('+Banking +Finance' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 100
```

**My Solution:**
I restructured the schema, I added a new table named "Categories" which has all the concatenated category from "Category" (with fulltext index) and off course a companyid. This does the job and this is the best / efficient way I can think of.

I have already tried different approaches like:
- group_concat + like
- union + full text

I am still wondering if there is a better way than my solution?

Answer (score 0):

This may work.  You can use a having clause to count how many times each word has a match.  It will show only ones that have at least one match for each word.

```
SELECT c.companyname 

FROM   Company c
       INNER JOIN Categoy cat ON c.id = cat.companyid

GROUP BY c.id

HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN MATCH (categoryname) AGAINST ('+Banking' IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
       AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN MATCH (categoryname) AGAINST ('+Finance' IN BOOLEAN MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1

LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. However, I have 15 million+ records/companies and this will be very slow. My solution to create a new table w/ csv categories is very much faster than this.